# mySQL - How can i find the maximum size of content in a field

Tags: mysql, max

I need to move some data.

I have a table with a field "answer" that has a Type of blob

How can I find the maximum size of the field for all records?

Some sort of select max(answer.size) from answers;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(FIELD)) FROM TABLE
```